# Differentiation of an integral (Lebesgue diffentiation theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, differential

I am reading Kolmogorov's textbook Introductory Real analysis, at the section 31.3. In the proof of theorem 8, he wrote "since the number of sets $E_{\alpha \beta}$ is countable, this will imply $\mu\{x:f(x)<F'(x)\}=0$". I include the page of the book here. I could not understand it why the countability implies measure zero, thought as a counterexample, I can pick two function $g_1 \equiv 1$ and $g_2 \equiv 2$, so $g_1<g_2$ and I can pick sets $E_{\alpha \beta}$ the same as in the proof, I am not about to show measure of $E_{\alpha \beta}=0$, just $\mu\{x:g_1(x)<g_2(x)\}$ can not be zero. In the proof as I understand he did not use $E_{\alpha \beta}=0$ to show $\mu\{x:f(x)<F'(x)\}=0$ but instead. Please give me a hint or explain it for me!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\{ x: f(x)<F'(x)\} \subset_{\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Q}}  E_{\alpha,\beta}$$

The union is countable, so
$$\mu (\{x:f(x)<F'(x)\})\le\sum_{\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{Q}}\mu(E_{\alpha,\beta})=0$$

Comment: Excuse me, 1) Why we already have $\mu(E_{\alpha \beta})=0$ before? I thought we are supposed to show that $\mu(E_{\alpha \beta})=0$ 2) As the counterexample I gave above, the countability of $E_{\alpha \beta} $ does not imply the zero measure of the set of $x$. 3) even if that implies, it does not make sense to me because, first we assume that $\alpha ,\beta$ are rational, then we use it, but it loses of generality, it is different if we chose $\alpha,\beta$ arbitrary, since that number does not have to be rational if $f(x) < F'(x)$

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I think here the author uses the fact that $\mu E_{\alpha \beta}=0$ and then he proves afterward. The text is just confusing to me somehow.

Comment: Yeah, notice he says “as we now show”